# How to remove an entry out of $GLOBALS['TCA'] (Table configuration array) in the Backend in TYPO3

Tags: typo3

I want to remove an entry in the select field in the plugins section of TYPO3. Basically where on can pick the list_type. I'd like to remove one. When I open the Configuration in the TYPO3 backend I see that all the configured extensions listed in:

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['columns']['list_type']['config']['items']
```

But how can I remove an entry of this array now in my Editor (PhpStorm)? I can't find the entries in the TCA/Overrides/tt_content...

Any help or hints are appreciated!

Best

Answer (score 1):

`TCEFORM.tt_content.list_type.removeItems := addToList(my_pi1,my_pi2)`

But in addition to this you should also study the documentation for `MOD` pageTSconfig, specifically the section about the new content wizard. Remember that removing an empty from TCA is far, far from enough to remove the corresponding meta configuration from all places. You will also create pageTSconfig and TypoScript setup by registering a plugin and this setup may also need to be removed.

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TSconfigReference/8.7/PageTsconfig/Mod/Index.html#new-content-element-wizard-mod-wizards-newcontentelement

The easiest way if this is one of your own plugins and you don't need it at all: avoid registering it. One way to do so is to make a condition for whether or not to register the plugin and control this with a toggle (ENV, context, extension config, etc.)

When you register a plugin in TYPO3 it creates quite a bit of configuration in addition to adding the items to either the `CType` or `list_type` selectors depending on registration method. This other configuration is as important as the TCA item.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove content element types (Ctypes) for editors, you could use Page TSConfig or User TSConfig. Add this to your backend user group or to the page (in the page properties Resources / Page TSConfig):

```
TCEFORM.tt_content.CType.removeItems := addToList(textpic,bullets,table,uploads)
```

This removes the element "textpic,bullets,table,uploads" in the backend for tt_content records.

Comment: thank you. But that's not exactly what I want. When you go to: NewContentElement ==> Plugins ==> General Plugin ==> Plugins. There is a list to choose the plugins. Here I'd like to delete the list_type... that is to say the name in the dropdown menu/select field.  Does that work similar?

Comment: basically I want to kick out an element from $GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['columns']['list_type']['config']['items'] ==> kick out item here